# override ambiguous inheritence

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm working on providing a set of serializing methods that need to be structure aware. I therefore built a class template that provides those methods to all class inheriting from it.

Here is what I have right now:

```
template<typename T>
class serializable
{
    protected:
        serializable() = default;
    public:
        size_t size_of() { return sizeof(T); }
        void   dump(void* data) { std::memcpy(data, this, serializable<T>::size_of()); }
        void   load(void* data) { std::memcpy(this, data, serializable<T>::size_of()); }
        virtual void serialize()
        {
            std::cout << "Default serialize : size " << serializable<T>::size_of() << std::endl;
        }
};

struct point : public serializable<point>
{
    float p[3];
};
struct particle : public point, public serializable<particle>
{
    float v[3];
};

int main()
{
    particle p;
    p.serialize();

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that when calling `p.serialize`, the compiler issues an ambiguous overload error between `serializable<point>::serialize()` and `serializable<particle>::serialize()`.

How can I solve this? Is there any way of overriding the inheritance from `serializable<point>` to only consider `serializable<particle>`? Should I consider another approach?

Comment: Inheritance doesn't seem appropriate here. A particle isn't a point.

Comment: I tried doing `struct particle : public serializable<particle>{ point p; point v; };` but that lead to a structure if size 56 and not 48 ... and I just can't accept data not to be aligned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bring in the one `serialize` you want:

```
struct particle : public point, public serializable<particle>
{
    using serializable<particle>::serialize;
    float v[3];
};
```

But likely you just want to use composition:

```
struct particle : public serializable<particle>
{
    point p;
    float v[3];
};
```

Comment: I think composition is the best approach, actually. You could add a conversion operator for `particle` to return `p`.

Comment: @jxh I agree. That's why I said "likely." Not sure about the conversion operator though...

Comment: Just a thought. It would cover passing a `particle` to a function wanting a `point` argument, for example.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I solve this ?

Override `serialize()` in `particle`. You'll need to serialize the point data and particle's own data anyway. The default implementation of `serialize` from the base class won't be able to do the right thing for `particle`.

You also need to override `serialize()` in `point` for the same reason.

Also, I think making `point` a base class of `particle` doesn't seem right. A `particle` is not a `point`. It has a location and velocity. An aggregation seems like the better approach to me.

```
struct point : public serializable<point>
{
   void serialize()
   {
      // Serialize p
      // ...
   }

   float p[3];
};

struct particle : public serializable<particle>
{
   void serialize()
   {
      // Serialize location.
      p.serialize();

      // Serialize velocity.
      // ...
   }

   point p; 
   float v[3];
};
```

**Problem in `serializable`**

Judging by your example usage of `serializable`, the lines:

```
    void   dump(void* data) { std::memcpy(data, this, serializable<T>::size_of()); }
    void   load(void* data) { std::memcpy(this, data, serializable<T>::size_of()); }
```

will lead to undefined behavior. The derived classes are not [TriviallyCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable). Using `std::memcpy` on such types will lead to problems in no time.

See the answers to [a question I had posted just last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777492/why-would-the-behavior-of-stdmemcpy-be-undefined-for-objects-that-are-not-triv).

Comment: I plan on overiding serialize for complex structure which includes pointers of stl container. However the point of the default serialize is to dump the data as a `char[size_of()]` using `dump`

Comment: @Amxx, That would be a problem since these classes are not PODs. You'll have to rethink your strategy. `sizeof(T)` will include not only the data but also the pointer to the virtual table.

Comment: After reading your update I'm now conserded about what is and isn't trivially copyable. My idea was that is the structures contains std::string / std::vector / other similar synamic object, then one would have to overide the serializing function. However I just don't get how it could be unsafe to use `std::memcpy` on a structure like `point` which is juste an array of floats ... also I tried to run `std::is_trivially_copyable` but the compilers says it's not a member of std (gcc 4.9.2 / clang 3.6.0)

Comment: @Amxx, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable describes when an object is trivially copyable and when it is not.

Comment: You'll need to use the compiler flag `-std=c++11` to get the C++11 features.

Comment: @R Sahu: I of course have this flag active (in fact I even have `-std=c++14`)

Comment: Not yet implemented :( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: @Amxx, that's unfortunate. gotta live with the limitations of your compiler.