# Is this defined

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, type-punning

Suppose I have a class `A`:

```
class A : virtual SomeOtherClass{
  //Stuff here
};
```

Suppose I have do this somewhere:

```
A thing;
alignas(A) uint8_t arr[sizeof(A)];
for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(A); x++)
{
  //Copy into array
  arr[x] = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&A)[x];
}

A* otherThing = reinterpret_cast<A*>(arr);
```

Is what I am doing here defined behavior, or am I killing myself in someway that I am unaware?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shown code executes something that's equivalent to `memcpy()`.

As such, [this is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777492/why-would-the-behavior-of-stdmemcpy-be-undefined-for-objects-that-are-not-triv). Classes with virtual base classes are not trivially-copyable.