# Segmentation fault when implementing my own data type

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Basically I am trying to implement my own data type similar to vector. I'm doing this just for fun. Thing is that I constantly get **Segmentation fault** when trying to put a new element of type **string** (tried to create a struct named **person** and it had the same problem). Piece of code which is I think most important in this case (**table.h**):

```cpp
template<typename type>
class table
{
    private:
        type* elements = new type[0];
        unsigned int length_ = 0;

        void resize(int change)
        {
            length_ = length_ + change;
            type* elements_ = new type[length_];

            std::memcpy(elements_, elements, length_ * sizeof(type));

            delete[] elements;
            elements = elements_;
        }

    public:
        /* ... */

        void put(type&& element)
        {
            resize(1);
            elements[length_ - 1] = element;
        }
}
```

Then (**main.cpp**):

```cpp
/* ... */

int main()
{
    table<string> t;
    t.append("Hello World"); // segfault
    for(string s : t) {cout << s << endl;}

    /* But this works:
    table<char*> t;
    t.append((char*)"Hello World");
    for(string s : t) {cout << s << endl;} */
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: The code provided does not reproduce the problem described.  And `std::memcpy` is being used on a non-memcpy-able object.

Comment: Don't use `new`: use `std::vector`. I've never seen `new` used in an initialization statement. It may work, it may not.

Comment: You can't use `memcpy` on general types like `string`. Roughly, a `string` contains a pointer to char where the actual string data resides. If we `memcpy` that, we get two strings with the same pointer, then when both are destructed we perform a double free on the same pointer which is undefined behavior. `memcpy` is only safe on very basic data types.

Comment: See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777492/why-would-the-behavior-of-stdmemcpy-be-undefined-for-objects-that-are-not-triv).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would the behavior of std::memcpy be undefined for objects that are not TriviallyCopyable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777492/why-would-the-behavior-of-stdmemcpy-be-undefined-for-objects-that-are-not-triv)

Answer (score 3):

In this code

```
length_ = length_ + change;
type* elements_ = new type[length_];

std::memcpy(elements_, elements, length_ * sizeof(type));
```

you're incrementing `length_` and then copying that many elements from your `elements` array into the new one. But `elements` only has `length_ - change` elements in it. So it's attempting to copy data from outside of the bounds of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Also as someone mentioned in the comments, you can't use `std::memcpy` for types like `std::string`. It can only be used for [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) types. You can do something like this instead:

```
unsigned int newLength = length_ + change;
type* elements_ = new type[newLength];
std::copy(elements, elements + length_, elements_);
length_ = newLength;
```

or better yet just use a `std::vector<type>`

```
template<typename type>
class table
{
    private:
        std::vector<type> elements;

    public:
        /* ... */

        void put(type&& element)
        {
            elements.emplace_back(std::move(element));
        }
}
```