# Can cv::Mat be safely recreated from its bitwise-serialized form?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory

Consider following code:

```cpp
cv::Mat currentFrame; // some proper frame with allocated memory

std::vector<uint8_t> storage;

{
    cv::Mat m1 = currentFrame.clone();
    cv::Mat m2 = m1;
    const auto *m1ptr = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(&m1);
    storage.insert(storage.end(), m1ptr, m1ptr + sizeof(cv::Mat));
    m1.addref();
}

{
    cv::Mat m3;
    uint8_t *dstPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&m3);
    std::copy_n(storage.begin(), sizeof(cv::Mat), dstPtr);
}
```

In the first scope I am working with a `cv::Mat` image, doing some copying to increase the refcount, and finally bitwise-serializing just the `cv::Mat` header (96 bytes) into the vector `storage`. Notice `m1.addref()`, where I increase the refcount by 1, so to avoid memory deallocation, when `m1` and `m2` get deleted, and refcount would drop to 0. Between the scopes, there is no actual `cv::Mat` pointing to allocated place in the memory, but the copy of such `cv::Mat` exists in the storage.

Then I try to restore it, by deserializing it from the storage. `m3` is now a copy of already gone `m1`, it points to still allocated memory block, and refcount=1. So I would expect everything to work. But when we reach the end of the scope and destructor of `m3` is called, I get **invalid pointer** exception. What is wrong with this design?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251419/discussion-on-question-by-piotr-g-can-cvmat-be-safely-recreated-from-its-bitwi).

Answer (score 0):

C++ objects are not just collections of bytes. You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777492) bitwise copy an arbitrary object into another object and pretend that you've recreated the original one. You can do it only for trivial types, and `cv::Mat` is not such a type. All tricks related to keeping matrix elements buffer from deallocation are irrelevant, because `cv::Mat` could have and actually does have other implementation details that prevent correct bitwise move.

Here is a simple example of a type that follows those details of `cv::Mat`:

```
struct S {
    int* a;    // = cv::Mat::step.p
    int  b;    // = cv::Mat::step.buf
 
    // other irrelevant data members including matrix elements buffer
 
    S() {
        a = &b;
    }
 
    ~S() {
        if (a != &b)
            delete a;
    }
};

std::vector<char> storage;
{
    S s1;
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s1);
    storage.insert(storage.end(), ptr, ptr + sizeof(S));
}
{
    S s2;
    char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s2);
    std::copy_n(storage.begin(), sizeof(S), ptr);
}
```

It should be pretty obvious what's wrong with bitwise overwriting `s2` with bitwise-serialized `s1`: you set `s2.a` to an address of `s1.b`. If you're lucky to have `s1` and `s2` at the same address, nothing bad will happen. If they are at different addresses, you'll `delete` a variable on stack. That's how UB looks: sometimes your code appears to work, sometimes it crashes.

Here is a complete demo you can play with: https://godbolt.org/z/5ezcaWv7x