# Avoid `-Wclass-memaccess` on memcpy of a POD type w/copy disabled

Tags: c++, gcc, memcpy, gcc-warning

If you turn up your warning level to `-Wall`, GCC 8 (at least `g++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.10.1) 8.3.0` with `--std=c++17`) gives `-Wclass-memaccess` on:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
   #include <type_traits>
#endif
#include <string.h>

struct CantCopy {
    int i;

  #ifdef __cplusplus
    CantCopy () = default;
    CantCopy (const CantCopy &other) = delete;
    void operator= (const CantCopy &rhs) = delete;
  #endif
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  #ifdef __cplusplus
    static_assert(std::is_pod<CantCopy>::value);
  #endif

    struct CantCopy src;
    src.i = 1020;

    struct CantCopy dest;
    memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof(struct CantCopy));

    return 0;
}
```

The warning says:

> warning: ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’ writing to an object of type ‘struct CantCopy’ with no trivial copy-assignment [-Wclass-memaccess]
>
> ```
> memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof(CantCopy));
> ```

What I have is code that's intended to build as either C or C++.  But the C++ build is supposed to be able to statically check when C programmers are going through direct assignments of the structure--when they should be using a function.  Hence disabling copying.

But it's still POD, and all this does was delete the operators.  I can see the [scenario this warning is designed to help with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26031024/211160), but this isn't that situation.

Is there any easy way to do something equivalent to this without needing to disable the warning?

Comment: Try typecasting the addresses to `char*`: `memcpy((char*)&dest, (char*)&src, sizeof(struct CantCopy)); 
`

Comment: Which version of C++ are you compiling with?  Is it C++17?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That seemed to do the trick!  Assuming it's not shady and breaking some other hidden rule to do so, that seems an answer to me, if you want to migrate the comment to a post...

Comment: @HostileFork Because I cannot imagine that this is a POD ...  It seems to violate [class]/6.2 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#6.2

Comment: @L.F. Er...well, I dunno.  I was under the impression that having the constructor `= default;` made it one...?  :-/  In any case, the only intent here is just to stop the type from being copied literally bytewise, outside of a few very specific and narrow safe points to do so (where memcpy is used).  If there is a more-standards-compliant-recipe for this intent, I'm all ears...just trying to get past a new warning that showed up.  (!)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to allow `memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof(struct CantCopy))`, but prohibit `dest = src`?  Because I don't see the difference between them

Comment: @L.F. For the type in question, *most* of the time it is not safe to blit the bytes.  The typical C client is supposed to call `Move_Value(&cantcopy_dest, &cantcopy_src)`, and there are some tweaks that happen during that movement (based on bit patterns at the destination location, which carries some formatting indicating what kind of destination it is, so the copy is sensitive to it).  A very few core routines actually do want to blit the bytes because they know they can, and they are the ones using memcpy().

Comment: Well, if that is the case, is providing a separate copy function an option?

Comment: It becomes a bit of a pain to go through a copy because of embedding; it's not just about this type, but where the type appears in other structures.  :-/  I'd be happiest if I can avoid creating parallel `#ifdef __cplusplus` code that calls methods, which then degrades to plain assignments in the C build.

Comment: @HostileFork "*The typical C client is supposed to call `Move_Value(&cantcopy_dest, &cantcopy_src)`*" - can't be helped in C, but in C++ you could add a move constructor and move assignment operator which both call `Move_Value()`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could achieve your aim to make assignments and copies in C++ outside of a designated function impossible better by making the assignment operator and copy constructor default and private and adding your `Move_Value(&cantcopy_dest, &cantcopy_src)` as a friend.

```
struct CantCopy;
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void Move_Value(CantCopy *cantcopy_dest, const CantCopy *cantcopy_src);
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif


struct CantCopy {
    int i;

#ifdef __cplusplus
    CantCopy () = default;
  private:
    CantCopy (const CantCopy &other) = default;
    constexpr CantCopy &operator= (const CantCopy &rhs) = default;

    friend void Move_Value(CantCopy *cantcopy_dest, const CantCopy *cantcopy_src);
#endif
};

struct Other
{
  CantCopy c;
};

void test()
{
    CantCopy c1;
    CantCopy c2;
    // fails: c3{c1};
    // fails: c2 = c1;
    Move_Value(&c1, &c2);
    Other o;
    Other o2;
    // also fails: o = o2;
}

void Move_Value(CantCopy *cantcopy_dest, const CantCopy *cantcopy_src)
{
    // do special stuff
    *cantcopy_dest = *cantcopy_src;
}
```

Comment: Hey, that seems to work as well (e.g. still says std::is_pod, beats the memcpy warning...)  From a sheer simplicity point of view, the char* cast seems less likely to scare the C programmers reading the code, but if there's any practical problems with that this looks like a good alternative!